# jQuery aborting ajax calls not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to abort all pending ajax calls if I click a button. I have the following javascript codes.

```
var MyApp = function() {
    this.xhrPool = [];
}

MyApp.constructor = MyApp;

MyApp.prototype.fetchDataFromApi = function() {
    var rows = $("tr.data-row");

    var _obj = this;

    rows.each(function(index, rowData){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "http://wwww.example.com/somepage/",
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR){
                _obj.xhrPool.push(jqXHR);
            },
            success: function(response){
                //do something here on successful call
            },
            complete: function(jqXHR){
                var i = _obj.xhrPool.indexOf(jqXHR);
                if(i > -1) _obj.xhrPool.splice(i,1);
            },
            error: function(request, status, error){
                //do something else here on ajax error
            }
        });

    });
}

MyApp.prototype.AbortAllAjaxCall = function(){
    if(this.xhrPool.length > 0){
        var xhrPoolLength = this.xhrPool.length;

        for(x in this.xhrPool){
            this.xhrPool[x].abort();
            this.xhrPool.splice(x,1);
            console.warn("Aborted "+x+" ajax calls");
        }

        alert(this.xhrPool.length+ " of "+xhrPoolLength+" calls aborted");
    }
}

var app = new MyApp();
```

***There are always 40 calls at once. I have throttled the ajax calls so that non of the call responds anything for few minutes. i.e. status of all 40 calls remain pending for few minutes.***

I have a button, upon clicking calls `app.AbortAllAjaxCall()`.
`app.AbortAllAjaxCall()` method aborts the ajax calls in a loop and finally alerts the length of aborted calls of length of total ajax calls.

**Problem**

However, the problem is that, by clicking the button all of the ajax calls should have been aborted, but it does not. I have to click buton 3-4 times to abort all ajax calls.

Can anybody shed light on what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you used splice so the index changed while looping. For example: when `x` is 0, you abort the first ajax and remove it from array so the element with index 1 will become the first and will not be aborted when `x` become 1. To solve this, you can loop from the end of array:

```
for (let x = this.xhrPool.length - 1; x >= 0; x--){
  this.xhrPool[x].abort();
  this.xhrPool.splice(x,1);
  console.warn("Aborted "+x+" ajax calls");
}
```

Or just set `xhrPool` to an empty array after aborting all the ajax without using splice:

```
for(x in this.xhrPool){
  this.xhrPool[x].abort();
  console.warn("Aborted "+x+" ajax calls");
}
this.xhrPool = [];
```